# system command is failing in php for some case

Tags: php

Hi We are facing a very critical issue with `PHP`. Actually i don't know whether it is `PHP` limitation or something else. We really need some expert advise. We are having a redirect application developed in `PHP` where we capture the variables of all incoming request and store it in database using system command.But Recently we have found for some records it is not able to capture the variable into the database though those variables are there in `APACHE` log file. Please advice what might be the problem, Because capturing variable is directly affecting business. Is it because of php system command limitation of not able to handle multiple request at a time?
Ex.

```
dt.php?key=46232X&fh=E30103ERCQSM4WOZU61&id=ERCWOZU61
```

This is the normal pattern of incoming request.
Code to capture source of incoming variable:

```
$query_string=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
 $referer=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
 $uri=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Apart from the above mentioned variable i can't put here but we are capturing all variables.

System Command which i am using

```
system("nohup php $folder_path/incoming-process.php $p_id $cd $query_string $referer $ipaddress $uid $vid $uri > /dev/null &");
```

incoming-process.php

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
error_reporting(0);

include_once('database.php');
$project_id =$_SERVER['argv'][1];
$cd=$_SERVER['argv'][2];
$query_string=$_SERVER['argv'][3];
$referer=$_SERVER['argv'][4];
$ipaddress=$_SERVER['argv'][5];
$user_id=$_SERVER['argv'][6];
$vendor_rule_id=$_SERVER['argv'][7];
$vendor_id=$_SERVER['argv'][8];
$uri=$_SERVER['argv'][9];

$uri=urldecode($uri);
$query_string=urldecode($query_string);
$ipaddress=urldecode($ipaddress);



 //inserting variables & other details into Vendor_incoming_Info                           

$url = $uri;
parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $parts);
$keys = array_keys($parts);
$total=substr_count($uri, '=');

$uri=mysql_real_escape_string($uri);

$insert_incoming_info="insert into Vendor_Incoming_Info( Vendor_Id,Variable_Name,Value,User_Id) VALUES";
 for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++){
     $var=$keys[$i];
     $value=$parts[$var];
     if($var!='cd'){
        $insert_incoming_info=$insert_incoming_info." ('$vendor_id','$var','$value','$user_id') ,";
     }

    }
$insert_incoming_info= substr($insert_incoming_info,0,-1);
    $insert_incoming_info=$insert_incoming_info." ;";    
    mysql_query($insert_incoming_info);
```

Comment: How do you store it “using system command”? What system command?

Comment: Gumbo I have updated my question please see.

Comment: Smells like [OS command injection](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/78.html) and maybe [SQL injection](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/89.html). Where do the variable values come from and how does *incoming-process.php* process them?

Comment: Echoing Gumbo, we'll need to see the code in `incoming-process.php`

Comment: Yeah i have updated my question.Please check it

Comment: And what about the source of the variable values before the `system` call?

Comment: By the way: you *are* vulnerable to SQL injection. You should read on [how to prevent them](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: … and you’re also vulnerable to OS command injection.

Comment: Thanks Gumbo. we are aware of both. Do you think is it happening because of that? Because in most cases it is working fine

Comment: The `&` is a special character in Unix shells that makes the command run in background. The `&` delimits the command and anything following is handled as a new command.

Answer (score 1):

You are vulnerable to both [OS command injection](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/78.html) and  [SQL injection](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/89.html).

In both cases you fail to ensure that the values get interpreted as intended, i. e., as string parameters.

As for OS command parameters, use [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg), e. g.:

```
$args = array(
    "php",
    "$folder_path/incoming-process.php",
    $p_id,
    $cd,
    $query_string,
    $referer,
    $ipaddress,
    $uid,
    $vid,
    $uri,
);
$args = array_map("escapeshellarg", $args);
$args = implode(" ", $args);
system("nohup $args > /dev/null &");
```

As for the SQL parameter values, have a look at [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114)

Comment: Thanks a ton Gumbo. Will implement and check it